# Select 2 DIV elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to figure out a simple way to enable me to select 2 DIV elements using JQuery - here is my attempt : http://jsfiddle.net/MarKP/5/

I need to limit the selections to just 2 and will use the class I add to get the selected objects.

Can anyone point me in a better direction

```
<div id="1">one</div>
<div id="2">two</div>
<div id="3">three</div>
<div id="4">four</div>

var selected = 0;
var prevSelect;
$('div').click(function() {
    if (selected == 2) {
        selected = 1;
        console.log(prevSelect);
        $('#' + prevSelect).removeClass('fill');
    }
    $(this).addClass('fill');
    prevSelect = $(this).attr('id');
    selected = selected +1;

});

div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.fill {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Please include your code here, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated your functionality to disallow any selection change if 2 divs are already selected unless you click a selected div to unselect it:

http://jsfiddle.net/MarKP/32/

```
$('div').click(function(e){
    var $et = $(e.target);
    if ($et.hasClass('fill')) { 
        $et.removeClass('fill');
    } else {
        if ($('.fill').length < 2) {
            $et.addClass('fill');
        }
    }
});
```

Old solution: http://jsfiddle.net/MarKP/11/

Comment: EDIT: removed unnecessary variable

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this:

```
$('.divclass').click(function(){
  var cnt=$('.divclass .selected').length;
  if(cnt>2) return;

  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

This will add the class `selected` to at most 2 `divclass` objects. To get the selected objects, you just call `$('.divclass .selected')`.

Comment: @ManseUK, I would argue that that's not intuitive at all, at best i would replace `return` with `$('.divclass.selected').removeClass('selected')`, so when you click a 3rd, the previous 2 both get deselected and you start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to remove the oldest one clicked (unless it is already selected), I'd maintain my own array like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/MarKP/17/

```
var selected = [];
$('div').click(function() {
    if( $.inArray( this, selected ) > -1 ) return;
    if( selected.length === 2 ) {
        $(selected.shift()).removeClass('fill');
    }
    selected.push($(this).addClass('fill')[0]);
});
```

Comment: thanks - and that is what i originally wanted to do .. but @mVChr gave me a better option. Thanks .. is it possible to select 2 correct answers on SO ?

Comment: @ManseUK: Ah, so you *did* want to deselect a selected one with a second click?

Comment: Nope - I wanted to only allow a maximum of 2 selected DIVs - the bit that is better about @mVChr's solution is the way to deselect - needing to actually click on the selected DIV rather than automatically deselecting the first selected DIV.

Comment: You answered the questions I asked - but I prefer his solution - I would like to "Tick" both yours and his answers - is that possible on here ?

Comment: @ManseUK: No, if @mVChr worked best for you, you should definintely "accept" his answer.

Comment: @ManseUK: You're welcome, but you gave mine the accept. I think you meant to give it to @mVChr instead. :o)

Comment: @patrick dw - Done .. mental note made : clicking the accept button toggles the previous selection ... very much like the question i had !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Only add a selected class if there are fewer than two divs returned from a selector for div.selected. Otherwise, remove the selected class. For instance:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("selected") && $("div.selected").length < 2) {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    }
});
```